# What will happen when macro definitions are nested?

Tags: c

```
// main.cpp
#define a aa
#define aa a
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int aa = 11;
}
```

As like the code above, the macro definition is nested. Is finally a = 1 or a = 11 ?

Comment: Have you tried adding a print statement to answer your own question? Why bring this here? (PS: if the file extension is CPP, this is likely not the appropriate tag to use when asking this question.)

Comment: The *definitions* aren't nested. The question is whether the replacement text is subject to recursive expansion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C 2018 6.10.3.4 2 discusses rescanning for more macro names after macro replacement and says:

> If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. Furthermore, if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not replaced…

Then, when `a` is replaced with `aa`, rescanning finds `aa` and replaces it with `a`. Then rescanning does not replace `a` since it has already been replaced.

Similarly, when `aa` is replaced with `a`, rescanning finds `a` and replaces it with `aa`. Then rescanning does not replace `aa` since it has already been replaced.

Answer (score 3):

Well, try running it with `gcc -E` which runs only the preprocessor. Which outputs the following preprocessed c file.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int aa = 11;
}
```

This is with all your `#define`s expanded. Apparently it leaves it as is, or maybe does a limited number of passes.